# Is there a way to include "and" operator in a case/match condition?

Tags: python-3.x, pattern-matching

According to [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#pep-634-structural-pattern-matching) wa can use the `OR` operator in a match/case as follows:

```
match True:
    case(condition_1 | condition_2):
        # code
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to do the same thing with the `AND` operator, like in this example:

```
match True:
    case(condition_1 & condition_2):
        # code
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you give a concrete example? How should it match two patterns at once?

Comment: @md2perpe I have two dictionaries, and I want to make sure that my `key` exists in both of these dictionaries `case('key' in dict_1 and 'key' in dict_2)`

Comment: Do you have other patterns or is that the sole condition?

Comment: @md2perpe Yes, I do. We can either have both of these conditions true, or just one of them, so we have 3 cases. I tried to do this if-else style but it makes my code too complicated and I have a code smell so I'm trying to do this using match-case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about doing something like this?

```py
cond1 = 'key' in dict_1
cond2 = 'key' in dict_2

match (cond1, cond2):
    case (True, True):
        ...
    case (True, False):
        ...
    case (False, True):
        ...
    case (False, False):
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think this is a great solution